# Scrollable content with fixed and aligned header and sidebar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a simple calendar component with a variable amount of rows and columns. Each row and column has a minimal height/width though, so it should be possible for scrollbars to appear when it won't fit the screen.

I would like the header (which shows days and resources) and sidebar (which shows the hours) to always be visible.

I got it working perfectly in the following example in Chrome:
http://plnkr.co/2zCEiY9ssLCWLXY3teBN

HTML:

```
  <body onload="init()">
    <div id="grid">
      <div id="corner"></div>
      <div id="head"></div>
      <div id="side"></div>
      <div id="content"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Javascript:

```
function init() {
  var grid = document.getElementById("grid");
  var corner = document.getElementById("corner");
  var head = document.getElementById("head");
  var side = document.getElementById("side");
  grid.addEventListener("scroll", function(event) {
    corner.style.top = grid.scrollTop+'px';
    corner.style.left = grid.scrollLeft+'px';
    head.style.top = grid.scrollTop+'px';
    side.style.left = grid.scrollLeft+'px';
  });
}
```

CSS:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  width: 700px;
  height: 700px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#grid {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: purple;
  overflow: auto;
}

#corner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  z-index: 200;
}

#head {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 1000px;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(208,228,247,1) 0%,rgba(115,177,231,1) 24%,rgba(10,119,213,1) 50%,rgba(83,159,225,1) 79%,rgba(135,188,234,1) 100%);
  border: 1px solid black;
  z-index: 100;
}

#side {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  height: 1000px;
  width: 100px;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(208,228,247,1) 0%,rgba(115,177,231,1) 24%,rgba(10,119,213,1) 50%,rgba(83,159,225,1) 79%,rgba(135,188,234,1) 100%);
  border: 1px solid black;
  z-index: 100;
}

#content {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1000px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #b4ddb4 0%,#83c783 17%,#52b152 33%,#008a00 67%,#005700 83%,#002400 100%);
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

However, when i open this example in IE11 or firefox, the header jitters when scrolling with the mousewheel. (dragging scrollbars seems fine) This appears to be an issue with the smooth scrolling functionality of the browsers.

I could listen to a scroll event and prevent the default behavior and manually scroll the content. This would basically prevent smooth scrolling in all browsers. However it would be nice to have a solution that doesn't do that.

So in short, i want the example in the link above to work correctly in IE. Without the jittering header when scrolling with the mousewheel.

Comment: Why are you making things complicated, just use position fixed

Comment: The problem with fixed positions is that elements are fixed in the viewport. I don't want that. I want them to stay next to the 'content' div, even if you would scroll the entire webpage instead of just that 'content' div.

Also, giving the sidebar a fixed position, stops it from scrolling up and down. I want to keep it on the left, not stop it from scrolling up and down. 

Similar for the header, i want it to stay on top, and keep it scrolling left and right.